# How to automate Job in Shell script to produce Latex files with Doxygen and type command make pdf to get pdf file?

Tags: perl, bash, latex, doxygen

I Succeded to get files in PDF with help of Doxygen (Linux)!
My task is to automate whole process with shell script

For example:

doxygen   doxygenfile  ->   Gives Latex Files
Then I type Manually
make pdf in the latex folder to get pdf files.

Can any one suggest to make this process automated to get pdf files directly without any manua interaction in between with help of Shellscipt(Bash)/ Perl Script?

Comment: Instead of the abstract example, you should provide us with an cmplete example with your actual commands, actual directory and file names. From that it is much more easy to make a script suggestion, abstracting out specific filenames.

Comment: You can create a configuration file for Doxygen, or pipe commands to it.  See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032280/specify-doxygen-parameters-through-command-line

Comment: My Task to produce Pdf Files with automaised Bash Code with Doxygen(Linux).....
I tried with 
>doxygen -g 
>doxygen DoxyFile (I have configured with INPUT and OUTPUT_Directory TAGS) 
INPUT (TAG)-> .h 
File OUTPUT_DIrectory is Destination Folder (Where Latex,RTF and HTML files are created) 
Now LATEX Files are created in LATEX Folder (OutputDir) 
Manually I typed 
> makepdf 
Then I got the PDF I wanted ,But now I want to automise this whole process with bash code with one single file (No ManualInteraction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest something like

```
doxygen -w latex header.tex doxygen.sty
```

for your doxygen command (you may want to consult with [the manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/doxygen_usage.html) for better usage of doxygen commands), and then compile it with latex or pdflatex, using appropriate command (in case you use `latex` command, you will then need to convert dvi to pdf). So the primitive shell script would look like

```
#!/bin/bash
#doxygen 
doxygen -w latex header.tex doxygen.sty myfile
#latex
pdflatex header.tex
```

N.B.: Make sure you have all the appropriate latex packages. Otherwise you have to download them beforehand.

Comment: It helps but with many errors !! May be I have written wrong!!
Complete Scenario is like this...

Comment: It helps but with many errors !! May be I have written wrong!!
Complete Scenario is like this...
My Task to produce Pdf Files with automaised Bash Code with Doxygen(Linux)

I tried with 
>doxygen -g
>doxygen DoxyFile  (I have configured with INPUT and OUTPUT_Directory TAGS)
INPUT (TAG)->    .h File
OUTPUT_DIrectory is Destination Folder (Where Latex,RTF and HTML files are created)

Now LATEX Files are created in LATEX Folder (OutputDir)
Manually I types 
> makepdf
Then I got the PDF I wanted 
But now I want to automise this whole process with bash code with one single file (No ManualInter)

Comment: <br> #!/bin/bash <br/>
#doxygen 
doxygen -w latex header.tex doxygen.sty DoxyFile
#latex
pdflatex header.tex
<code>

Comment: doxygen -w latex header.tex doxygen.sty DoxyFile   
#latex  
pdflatex header.tex  

DoxyFile (TAGS):
INPUT : path for my input file     .h
OUTPUT_Directory = Path for the putput files in LATEx,HTML and RTf folders are created

Comment: #!/bin/bash
#doxygen
doxygen -w latex header.tex doxygen.sty DoxyFile
#latex
pdflatex header.tex

DoxyFile (TAGS):
INPUT : path for my input file     .h
OUTPUT_Directory = Path for the putput files in LATEx,HTML and RTf folders are created

*ERRORS*
Runaway argument?
\fancyplain {}{\bfseries \scriptsize Generated on Fri Apr 5 12:32:15 \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@xrfoot was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.52       \par
               \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}

Comment: I am really sorry for this comments.. I am just trying to Print LINe by LINe but ,Time duration is out by the time i add the line breaks <br/>

Comment: your script is simple enough to work fine, so the problem should be in your DoxyFile file. Have you googled the error you get? Does it appear when you act with doxygen or when you compile with latex?

Comment: It extracts header.pdf file evethough there exits errors .
Problem is it is not extracting pdf files in the specified folder in OUTPUT_directory Tagin DoxyFile.  It gives out pdf file in the same directory where i have DoxyFile.
I have googled the problem, but I havent come across right answer yet.I ams till trying

Comment: If I do it manually like  
doxygen  -g  ;
doxygen DoxyFile  ;   Go to the Folder where Latex folder is specfied in OUTPUT_DIRECTORY tag in DoxiFile and type   make pdf ;
I got the pdf file I wanted;
But here in this case while using this bash code stated above Files are created in the same folder instead of specified OUTPUT DIRECTORY

Comment: you can "cheat" a bit by moving them via mv command (include this to your script). though, i think there should be a better solution